# Skypekit integration with web application asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have to integrate skypekit on web application using vb.net
I have successfully created this application for the single user on web, but the code is not working in case of two parallel user with same credentials which is running on server.
It says "IPC socket time out" whenever I am going to start for another user.

I need some solution as quickly as possible.

Comment: My guess would be that you are trying to create two connections to Skype from the same machine, and that this is failing.  I don't know, but I suspect that SkypeKit is not designed for such a scenario.

Comment: No, actually I hosted application on IIS server 6.0 and hit the url from two different computer. but the problem is when one session is active the other will automatic get close and cause run time failure.My idea is two generate different p2p connection for skype chat on same server for different client.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said. If your app is hosted on IIS then you're creating two connections from your IIS server, which probably isn't possible with Skypekit.